# Why is this not converting all instances?

Tags: java, string, replace

I do not know why this code is not converting all instances of 'm' to 'M' and instances of 'M' to 'm'. For example, it should be converting to:

```
Report 98-17, Faculty of Technical matheMatics and InforMatics,%:m 2:M 1:
```

when it is converting to:

```
Report 98-17, Faculty of Technical MatheMatics and InforMatics,%:m 2:M1:
```

Thanks.

```
public static int numberOccurances(String l, char f){ 
    int count=0; 
    for(int x=0; x<l.length();x++){ 
        if(l.charAt(x)==f) 
            count++;    
    }
    return count; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    File file = new File("Old.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("New.txt", "UTF-8");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    int numberm=numberOccurances(line, 'm');
    int numberM = numberOccurances(line, 'M');
    for(int y=0; y<line.length(); y++){
        if(line.charAt(y)=='M'){
            line=line.substring(0,y) + 'm' + line.substring(y+1);
        }
        if(line.charAt(y)=='m'){
            line=line.substring(0,y) + 'M' + line.substring(y+1);
        }
    }
    if(numberm>0&&numberM>0)
        line=line + "%:m " + numberm + ":M" + numberM + ":";
    if(numberm>0&&numberM==0)
        line=line + "%:m " + numberm + ":";
    if(numberM>0&&numberm==0)
        line=line + "%:M " + numberM + ":";
    writer.println(line);
}
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't use an `else`, so when you modified `M` to `m`, the second `if` detects the `m` and reverses the effect.

So modify

```
if(line.charAt(y)=='M'){
    line=line.substring(0,y) + 'm' + line.substring(y+1);
}
if(line.charAt(y)=='m'){//pay attention to this line
    line=line.substring(0,y) + 'M' + line.substring(y+1);
}
```

into

```
if(line.charAt(y)=='M'){
    line=line.substring(0,y) + 'm' + line.substring(y+1);
}
else if(line.charAt(y)=='m'){//pay attention to this line
    line=line.substring(0,y) + 'M' + line.substring(y+1);
}
```

However I would recommend a regex to do this type of things. It makes life easier and it will increase performance.